# How to append a condition at the end of a sql query in WHERE and force it to take effect no matter what? (Query access control)

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql, access-control

i have to write an access control for queries made by doctors **(they can write query in a text box, don't ask why its a long story, its a project and not a real world scenario)** and i have to force the doctor to only see his own patients in the patient table, my approach was appending something like " AND doctor_id = $doctor_id" in the application

and the patient table is something like (name, id , doctor_id , ...)

but the problem is queries like this :

"select * from patients where 1=1 OR 2=2"

the doctor can simply say that query and bypass this, and i have to implement this in the application and not database

so how can i do it? how can i append something like that at the end of query that it would work no matter what they type before that? or do you have a better suggestion?

(and there has to be an option for them to write query so removing that is not an option)

i have a parser for this but i want them to able to write something like select * from patients and only get their own patients in that table.

Comment: `select * from patients where 1=1 or 2=2` just same like `select * from patients`.. Will better put your sample data and expected result.. It will easy to understand..

Comment: @dwir182 no i meant they can write that query, and therefore i cant append something like DOCTOR_ID = x at the end

Comment: What `rdbms` you are using?

Comment: Why do doctors have to write the SQL? Surely much better for them to be given a unique ID and run a proc instead with their ID which lists the patients for them only. If the frontend also passes in this ID from an authentication layer this forces correct access controls as well.

Comment: i would recommend to take the string, they have entered in the editbox and take it apart. After that, my approach would be to filter out all special characters like "-" and then add the parts to some default query you have like select x.* from (*Your Text*)x

Comment: @dwir182 postgresql, but i want to force this in the application if possible and not implement it in database, because i think that way i have to create a user in database for every doctor!

Comment: In e.g. SQL Server, one might arrange for the session to be aware of the user identity and use that to filter a view. Then you give them select permissions on the view, not the table.

Comment: In general i would highly recommend to prevent any user to write sql queries themselves...

Comment: @RichCampbell   its a project for implementing access control ourselves, not a real world scenario

Comment: Don't give access to the base table. Create a view instead, with a condition `select * from patients where doctor = current_user` something. Only give access to that view.

Comment: @jarlh so i should create a view for every doctor in the application and then query on that correct? thats a good idea actually, but wish i could've just appended something at the end instead of that

Comment: No, just one view. The `doctor = current_user` condition filters the rows for the current doctor. (Each doctor must have its own login.)

Comment: @jarlh but that way i should create a user for every doctor in the database too tho right? because in my application i just connect doctors to one username(doctors) in the database,   i have access to their username in the application but not database, in app i store it in the session

Comment: @RichardJones - I would say it's not really a good test for a project on access control because allowing a text box with unrestricted SQL query entry is a perfect point for a SQL injection attack. The stored proc with an ID passed in for each doctor is more optimal than a view for each doctor.

Comment: Correct, each doctor should have its own database user. This way you can track each users changes as well.

Comment: @jarlh but isn't that a lot of overhead? is it normal? i mean i have to create a username for other groups of people as well, can't i implement this in some other way in the application?

Comment: I agree with @jarlh - the first rule of database access control is unique IDs per person and no use of shared logins. This is especially key for something like a doctor or similar with confidential information. Would you share your online banking ID with another member of your family? Also bear in mind that for MS SQL for example you can grant access at the AD group level but still audit changes made by a single person you don't necessarily need to create separate users in the db it depends on your RDBMS.

Comment: @RichCampbell but is it normal to have like 500-600 usernames that can access database?! because there are other groups as well that can send query, is there any other way to implement it in application? maybe adding something to the query? it would be much cleaner if i had only one group of doctors in the database usernames and just tweak the query in the application

Comment: I've been involved in medical database systems with far more users than that.

Comment: @jarlh i thought about this approach but there is a problem, i have to use grant for each of them because for example i have to say doctors can only access 2 tables and only can update or read them, and there are other groups as well, so i have to do this for 600-700 users if i do this

Comment: @RichardJones - Yes on an RDBMS which doesn't support LDAP/Active Directory type authentication hundreds or thousands of logins/users in a database instance would be perfectly normal.Then you use roles/groups to segregate these into functions for your data access controls. With Active Directory for example with MS SQL Server this is easier as just create an AD group for each function then permission it accordingly within the database and at the same time you can permission their network drive or other access on the network with the same AD group.

Comment: You can still permission access with roles/groups - you don't need to (or want to) add rights for those hundreds of logins separately.

Comment: @jarlh whoops i think i got it, i think i have to filter the result instead, let them query what they want in the patients, and then just show them their own patients instead of all :D ( at the end i show them the patients in a table, i can just not show other patients to them)

Comment: thanks everyone for your helps i think i got it

Answer (score 1):

You could remove permissions to read the base table and create a temporary view to act as the table before  each query is run, or after user sign on to the application. Temporary views are per-session so there will be no name conflict between concurrent sessions.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW patients
  AS SELECT * FROM patients_base_table WHERE doctor_id = 1234;
```

If there is only database user and it doesn't have the read permission to `patients_base_table`, it's another user with the right permissions that should create this view. This can be done through the `SECURITY DEFINER` mechanism, where a function is executed with the privileges of its creator rather than the caller:

```
-- Create this function as the privileged user that owns the patients table
CREATE FUNCTION create_view(doctor_id int) RETURNS void
AS $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW patients  AS '
          'SELECT * FROM patients_base_table WHERE doctor_id=' || doctor_id;
  EXECUTE format('GRANT SELECT ON patients TO %I', session_user);
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER;
```

It's not bullet proof since a doctor could always call `create_view(other_doctor)` if they have full access to the database with shared credentials, but there's only so much you can with shared credentials...